# Getting Checkboxes value from form and storing true/false or 1/0

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form for Ticket purchasers to fill out after they have bought their tickets, I need name, where they are coming from, and Interests (which are checkboxes). I also need to be able to add fields dynamically so I'm already using an array. I've gotten it connected to my database and I am storing the correct data in the text/inputs. but the checked boxes are filling at random. I understand that the unchecked boxes aren't being sent so i need to assign them some sort of value either way? Here is what I have working so far:

```
<?php 
//Include the database class
require("db.class.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Vizion Conference Registration Form</title>
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
            $('<div id="guest' + i +'"><p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="first[]" size="20" name="first[]" value="" placeholder="First" /></label><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="last[]" size="20" name="last[]" value="" placeholder="Last" /></label><h3>Interests<small>(Select all that apply)</small></h3><div id="cat"><label><input type="checkbox" id="Soc[]" name="option1[]" value="1">Social Media</label><label><input type="checkbox" id="Web[]" name="option2[]" value="1">Website</label><label><input type="checkbox" id="Vid[]" name="option3[]" value="1">Video</label><label><input type="checkbox" id="Des[]" name="option4[]" value="1">Design</label><label><input type="checkbox" id="Mar[]" name="option5[]" value="1">Marketing</label><label><input type="checkbox" id="Aud[]" name="option6[]" value="1">Audio</label><label><input type="checkbox" id="Leg[]" name="option7[]" value="1">Legal</label><label>Other<input type="input" id="other[]" name="option8[]" value=""></label></div></p><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parent('div').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
//If form was submitted
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {

//create instance of database class
$db = new mysqldb();
$db->select_db();

//Check if user has actually added additional fields to prevent a php error
if (isset($_POST['first'])) {

    //get last inserted userid
    $inserted_Guests_id = $db->last_insert_id();

    for ( $i=0;$i<count($_POST['first']);$i++) {
        $FirstName = $_POST['first'][$i];
        $LastName = $_POST['last'][$i];
        $HomeChurch = $_POST['hmch'];
        $SocialMedia = isset($_POST['option1']) ? 1 : 0 ;
        $Websites = isset($_POST['option2']) ? 1 : 0;
        $Video = isset($_POST['option3']) ? 1 : 0;
        $Design = isset($_POST['option4']) ? 1 : 0;
        $Marketing = isset($_POST['option5']) ? 1 : 0;
        $Audio = isset($_POST['option6']) ? 1 : 0;
        $Legal = isset($_POST['option7']) ? 1 : 0;
        $Other = $_POST['option8'][$i];

    $sql_Guests = sprintf("INSERT INTO Guests (FirstName, LastName, HomeChurch, SocialMedia, Websites, Video, Design, Marketing, Audio, Legal, Other) VALUES ('$FirstName','$LastName','$HomeChurch','$SocialMedia','$Websites','$Video','$Design','$Marketing','$Audio','$Legal','$Other')");  
$result_Guests = $db->query($sql_Guests);

    }

    //Loop through added fields
    }else {

    //No additional fields added by user

}
echo "<h1>User Added, <strong>" . count($_POST['first']) . "</strong> website(s) added for this user!</h1>";

//disconnect mysql connection
$db->kill();
}
?>
<?php if (!isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) { ?>
<h2>Vizion Conference Registration Form</h2>

<form action="reg.php" method="post">
<div id="p_scents">
<label>Home Church</label><input type="text" name="hmch" id="hmch" placeholder="Somewhere Bible Church" />

<h2 style="float:left; margin-right:10px">Guests</h2>
<h3 style="float:left"><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add another Guest</a></h3><div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Register" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `id="Leg[]"` etc. is not allowed. Your code is hard to read, maybe there are other problems too.

Comment: Ok, this is my first php/mysql project so im still learning. So i can't use [] with ids?